# Adding "Share with messenger" button in website

Tags: html

Can anybody help me in adding the share with messenger button in website which opens like this image ?? [image]

Comment: Welcome, Shahriyar! For getting useful answers, you will need to provide some more information about what you are trying to. If I am getting this right, you want to create a button on your website to share some content, and that button will lead to a page where you can add comments to the content you want to share. If so, it requires more than one tool. It is important for you to specify what you have tried / what you known.

Answer (score 2):

If you run the link given below in your mobile browser , you can find this page
`fb-messenger://share?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com&app_id=1234567890` .
If you want this page for your desktop browser , open the following link
`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com&app_id=1234567890`